# Nodemon run specific command when specific file changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, watch, nodemon

> nodemon -w abc -x echo 'just watch abc folder' && nodemon -i abc -x echo 'watch all folder except abc folder'

If you looks script above, I'm trying to watch my `abc` folder, and when something changes inside them it will run `echo 'just watch abc folder'` without run `echo 'watch all folder except abc folder'`. What I know today is nodemon just restart the hole thing when something has changes.

What I need is it will run specific command when specific folder has changes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for short reply and too late, but if still relevant then consider using `--exec` option, example from docs:

```
nodemon --exec "python -v" ./app.py
```